# VBA versus VB.NET - triggering Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2013

I'm fairly experienced in VBA and automating various applications; Internet Explorer being one of them. I recently made the jump to VB.NET / Visual Studio (2013). When it comes to automating with VBA / VB.NET one will sometimes need to trigger certain JavaScript functions in order to interact with a webpage.

In VBA this is done by first enabling the "JScript" Reference. Below is an example of how to trigger a JavaScript function:

```
Call ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript("someFunction();", "JavaScript")
```

I have attempted to accomplish the same in Visual Studio using the invokeScript and execCommand methods to no avail. The function is valid as I am able to trigger it via the developer console (F12). Is there a different method I should be using? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

unsuccessful example:

```
webbrowser1.document.invokeScript("someFunction")
```

Comment: IIRC, it is: `WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript(Script, "JavaScript")`

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you sir! :)